# NodeJS write file to AWS S3 - Promise.All with async/await not waiting

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I writing a number of files to AWS S3 using NodeJS. I have the data in a stringifed variable but have also tested reading in a file. The files write successfully to S3 so it does work but the "await Promise.all()" completes before the file uploads complete. I need to know when the files have completed uploading.

```
    // Stream File Data to S3
    const data = "blah blah blah"
    const s3Path = "my_path"
    const promises = []
    promises.push(uploadFile(data, `${s3Path}/1111.xml`))
    promises.push(uploadFile(data, `${s3Path}/2222.xml`))
    promises.push(uploadFile(data, `${s3Path}/3333.xml`))
    promises.push(uploadFile(data, `${s3Path}/4444.xml`))
    const completed = await Promise.all(promises)
```

below is the function I'm using to upload the files.

```
const uploadFile = (data, key) => {

     // const fileContent = data
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync("/full_path/test.xml")

    // Setting up S3 upload parameters
    const params = {
        "Bucket": "my_bucket",
        "Key": key,
        "ContentType": "application/xml",
        "Body": fileContent
    }

    // Uploading files to the bucket
    s3.upload(params, (err, data2) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        }
        console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data2.Location}`)
        return true
    })
}
```

Is there a way to update this so promise.all() waits for all uploads to completed before progressing?

thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `uploadFile()` does not return a promise.  And, `Promise.all()` only does something useful when you pass it an array of promises that are tied to their asynchronous operations.

I suspect that `s3.upload()` has a promise interface that you should be using.

```
const uploadFile = async (data, key) => {

    const fileContent = await fs.promises.readFile("/full_path/test.xml");

    // Setting up S3 upload parameters
    const params = {
        "Bucket": "my_bucket",
        "Key": key,
        "ContentType": "application/xml",
        "Body": fileContent
    }

    // Uploading files to the bucket
    const data2 = await s3.upload(params).promise();
    console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data2.Location}`);
    return true;
}
```

Now `uploadFile()` returns a promise that resolves when the asynchronous operations in it are done (or rejects is there's an error).  So, then when you push the results of `uploadFile()` to an array and pass that to `Promise.all()`, it will be able to tell you when they are all done.

---

FYI, if `uploadFile()` always reads the same fileContent every time, then you ought to read that once outside the function and perhaps pass the data into `uploadFile()`.

---

FYI, here's some [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html) on using promises in the Javascript interface.  Worth reading.